# Accessing OlExchangeStoreType from outside Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm currently working on a small application that allows me to make some changes to a user's profile, namely add or remove specific PST files and transferring Contacts/Calendars from attached PST files into their primary mailbox.  This is for Outlook 2007.  After some searching, I found an enumeration in Outlook that I would like to use if possible: OlExchangeStoreType.

I want to use it to help determine which store I'm operating on (eg, public, primary, or PST file).  I'm just not sure how I can reach it.  I'm using late binding in my code to work around possible problems moving between different versions.  Current Binding:

```
Dim olApp,olNS
On Error Resume Next
    olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Else
        olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    End If
```

This works fine.  If I try GetObject(, "Outlook") instead, I get "Cannot create ActiveX component."

Is there an interface I can use for Outlook that will give me access to the public enumerations?

And as for why I'm doing it this way, I don't want to have to deal with macro security nor pushing out the macro to multiple users.  I'm also new to using VBA so there may be an easier method than what I'm trying to do.

Let me know what you think.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  I was originally under the impression that the enumeration values were objects of a class, but they're just integers.

I found that
     StoreObj.ExchangeStoreType

will return an integer that matches what OlExchangeStoreType uses.  I'll just recreate the enum in my class.

Thanks,